# Como saber a versão da biblioteca Jquery apenas visualizando os códigos feitos por outros usuários?

Tags: html, jquery, css, biblioteca

Estou com pequeno código jquery aqui, oferecido por um membro desse site que acabei achando, e não sei qual versão da biblioteca devo carregar e executar o código alheio. Não tenho como comentar na resposta que ele deu a outro usuário por causa na minha reputação, que biblioteca devo adicionar?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ckAll").click(function()  {  // minha chk que marcará as outras

if ($("#ckAll").prop("checked"))   // se ela estiver marcada... 

$(".chk").prop("checked", true);  // as que estiverem nessa classe ".chk" tambem serão marcadas
     else $(".chk").prop("checked", false);   // se não, elas tambem serão desmarcadas

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se essa é a resposta ideal, mas a minha dica seriá sempre usar a versão mais atual! Pois teoricamente ela sempre corrigi e melhora as versões anteriores.

Então depois que vc colocar a versão mais atual vc testa para ver se funciona. Se rodar ok. Se der erro, vc pode pode consultar a **documentação oficial** se algo do código está como **deprecated**. Se vc ver no Console que tem algum erro, vc identifica o erro, pega o nome do método, e consulta na documentação aqui: https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

**Outra dica** é olhar a data da postagem de onde vc pegou o código e verificar qual era a versão da data nessa lista de **Releases Dates** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É bem viável mesmo olhar para data da publicação do usuário, thanks!

Comment: @ElienayJunior isso pode eliminar boa parte das chances de pegar a versão errada acredito. Boa sorte ai! Mas tente testar com a vesão mais nova primeiro, só pega as antigas se vc tiver algum erro.

Comment: @dvd a minha resposta se enquadra na categoria "jeitinho brasileiro" haha. Não é perfeita nem de longe, mas acho que ajudou no caso do colega aqui. Tb não entendi vc levar esse downvote, pra mim é uma resposta válida. A propósito, a foto do Blanca é bem melhor :D []'s